# Table Valued Function in Entity Model Not Visible Through WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2013

I have successfully imported a Table Valued Function into our entity model using EF5, which we expose via WCF DataServices.

From within the project that houses the model and WCF service, we can access and the imported TVF function no problem.  But from within our client applications that consume the service, the TVF is nowhere to be found in code or the object browser.

How can we expose the TVF through the WCF service so we can call it from our client apps?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to manually register TVFs as methods on your service, and then manually toss some service operation access rights to that method in the static config/init routine, like so:

```
 [WebGet]
 public IQueryable<LongJohns> GetFancyPants(Nullable<int> size)
 {
     return this.CurrentDataSource.FancyPantsTVF(size).AsQueryable();
 }
```

...and hook it up somewhere in the service initializer:

```
// This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetFancyPants", ServiceOperationRights.All);
}
```

Now I don't know if this is because I'm still clinging to EF5 or something, but oddly enough it took longer than I hoped for to find hints and get this to work. After doing the above, it instantly worked for me anyway.

Comment: Do you perchance know whether optional parameters are supported in TVF's called via WCF?